# Docker container gives No binary for Chrome browser on your platform

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, google-chrome

I'm running Angular unit tests in a Docker container and getting this error:

```
21 01 2021 01:51:10.057:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
21 01 2021 01:51:10.063:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
21 01 2021 01:51:10.097:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
```

To run the tests I am simply running .. ng test .. using the image node:14 from Docker Hub

Is there an almost identical (preferably official) image that I can use that also has Chrome all ready to go on it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to run this on build server:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable xvfb
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

All the instructions except the last install Chrome.
The last installs Angular and is not needed if you are not using Angular.

NOTE: I had to have Chrome installed because ng test uses Chrome - however, I've since switched to Jest which I believe can run unit tests without Chrome installed - although I haven't checked this.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for systems that use yum (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, etc.). Needed for karma or other frameworks that use real browsers to test (jest does not).

```
echo -e '[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
yum install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here with a slightly different issue, but the same error. The answer I used is the last line of the error message:

```
Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
```

This can be to wherever you have installed Chrome or indeed Chromium. Obviously if you haven't got them installed then install them first.

For my setup I've got flatpak [Chrome](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.google.Chrome) and Chromium installed on Pop_OS! (with Ubuntu underlying it). Running:

```bash
export CHROME_BIN=~/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.google.Chrome/current/active/export/bin/com.google.Chrome
```

Then re-running the commands worked.