# No binary for ChromeHeadless browser on your platform.Please,set"CHROME_BIN" env variable

Tags: angular

I am getting this error while deploying my angular code on Jenkins.

Tried multiple solution but did not work.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --no-watch --code-coverage --browsers ChromeHeadless --source-map=false",
    "test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
```

karma.conf.js

```
browsers: ['Chrome'],
```

Comment: hello did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837359/docker-container-gives-no-binary-for-chrome-browser-on-your-platform?

Comment: can you try to correct from `browsers=ChromeHeadless` to `--browsers=ChromeHeadless` on test:ci npm command line ?